# PlatformException-permission denied Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Two days ago Firestore stopped working since I needed to update security rules, now I did it and changes are fine I'm able to use Firebase again but my functions are not working anymore.

This is the line that causes Exception :

```
var ref = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("uids")
      .doc("${uid[0] + uid[1]}")
      .collection(uid)
      .doc(uid)
      .get();
```

Firestore rules :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  
  match /uids/{twoLetters}/{UserUid}/{anyDoc=**} {
    allow read, write : if true;
  }
}
```

The error is :

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(permission-denied, The caller does not have permission
to execute the specified operation., {code: permission-denied,
message: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.,
nativeErrorMessage: Missing or insufficient permissions., nativeErrorCode: 7}, null))
```

Since rules are inconsistent (  `allow read, write : if true` ) I don't understand why the user doesn't have permissions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you might need to add the time. For example you could do:

```java
allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 6, 1);
```